# How do I write custom a custom api-derive?

Tags: polkadot-js, api

I am trying to create my own derives using DeriveCustom like this:

```
import { DeriveCustom } from '@polkadot/api-derive';
import * as staking from './staking';

export const derive: DeriveCustom = {
  customStaking: staking as unknown as DeriveCustom[string]
};
```

```
import { derive as customDerive } from '@my-network/api-derive';
// ...
export const options = ({
// ..
derives: {
    ...customDerive,
  }
// ..
}
```

but when I try to use `api.derive.customStaking`, it is not recognized by typescript.

Comment: I stumbled on this, seems like derives can be augmented now - https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4577

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [`@polkadot/api` issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4577). Basically the poster had the same question.

In this case it led to [an enhancement](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/pull/4578) making the derives augmentable (usage below copied from this PR) and that went out into the wild as part of the [7.9.1 release](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/releases/tag/v7.9.1)

```js
// augmentDerives.ts
import type { Observable } from 'rxjs';

declare module '@polkadot/api-derive/derive' {
  // extend, add our custom section
  export interface ExactDerive {
    customPallet: {
      someMethod: ReturnType<() => () => Observable<number[]>>
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Giving credit where credit is due - @RosaryBeads did mention the exact same link in a comment above, I didn't see it when posting this... Keeping it here since my expansion on the usage as well as version adds enough additional context.

Comment: An example that I used is found in this [custom derives](https://github.com/xx-labs/web-wallet/tree/fcdcd4f5ddeeb69c272e4550fde3353ecd0328b7/packages/custom-derives) module, imported with `import custom from './custom-derives'` and api constructed with `const api = await ApiPromise.create({ derives: custom, provider });`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I cast to any:

```
await (api.derive as any).customDerive.method()
```

But this loses intellisense and type checking.